# Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)

Tags: eclipse, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to implement the below code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.Mention;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

public class CorefResolver {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Annotation document = new Annotation("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He is the president. Obama was elected in 2008.");
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref");
  StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
  pipeline.annotate(document);
  System.out.println("---");
  System.out.println("coref chains");
  for (CorefChain cc : document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class).values()) {
  System.out.println("\t" + cc);
  }
  for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
  System.out.println("---");
  System.out.println("mentions");
  for (Mention m : sentence.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefMentionsAnnotation.class)) {
    System.out.println("\t" + m);
    }
  }
 }
}
```

This is a code from stanford corenlp. I have used eclipse as framework. Below image shows the view in eclipse.

[image]

While running the code, I am getting the below error. I have tried including models taggers etc. Still showing the same error.

```
Adding annotator tokenize
No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$4.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:245)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:152)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:451)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:154)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:150)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:137)
at CorefResolver.main(CorefResolver.java:16)
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:791)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:312)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:265)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:85)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:73)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.posTagger(AnnotatorImplementations.java:63)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$4.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:243)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as class path, filename or URL
at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:470)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:789)
... 12 more
```

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I found adding the `models` classifier dependency worked.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Kotlin Gradle dsl (build.gradle.kts) this worked for me:

```
val corenlp_version = "4.2.2"
```

If you don't want to use the previous variable, you can substitute the value:

```
implementation("edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:$corenlp_version")
implementation("edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:$corenlp_version:models")
implementation("edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:$corenlp_version:models-english")
implementation("edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:$corenlp_version:models-english-kbp")
```

Comment: I have implemented this solution for my backend Java application and it works. I removed the variable and added directly the version in the gradle file. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Included Stanford corenlp 3.8 jar and Stanford corenlp 3.8 models. Now the coreference resolution is working

[image]jar